# Equivalent of "Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial" in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

What is the equivalent of

> Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial

in Yii2 ??

Comment: There is no equivalent; both methods are called exactly the same and are called in exactly the same way.

Comment: @topher there is nothing wrong with the question. from the amount of views, you will see that many including myself have typed this questions into search engine and clicked on this link.

Answer (score 18):

in yii2

```
Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('myview');
```

Answer (score 15):

In view files, `$this` refers to `yii\web\View` object so simply call:

```
$this->render('partials/_profile', ['name'=>'value']);
```

and it will work.

Or pass and absolute path to `renderFile()` to skip the call to `findViewfile()`:

```
$this->renderFile(dirname(_FILE__) . '/partials/_profile.php', ['name'=>'value']);
```

Comment: Do not foget add echo!    echo $this->render('partials/_profile', ['name'=>'value']);

Answer (score 0):

Yii2, differently of Yii1, uses namespaces. So to call the renderPartial() function you'll need before to call the "yii\base\Controller" namespace, then use renderPartial() function.